# Missing required parameter: scope on Python OAuth Call for YouTube Data API

Tags: youtube-api

I'm getting "Missing required parameter: scope" when calling flow.run_console() in Python. The consent screen pops up with this error in the browser. I have an application that I'm creating that will run on a Linux server to download and store our YouTube data daily without user intervention. I followed the coding examples and have tried several different ways to do this call. I always get the error about a missing scope parameter. I'm trying to make this call to get the initial authorization for the YouTube Data API. The following is the current version of my code that is making the call:

```
def get_youtube_service(**kwargs):
    #create_client_secret_file()
    flow = google_auth_oauthlib.flow.InstalledAppFlow.
               from_client_secrets_file(CLIENT_SECRETS_FILE, scopes)
    storage = Storage("youtubeapi-oauth2.json")
    credentials = storage.get()

    if credentials is None or credentials.invalid:
        credentials = flow.run_console(**kwargs)

    return googleapiclient.discovery.build(API_YOUTUBE_SERVICE_NAME, API_YOUTUBE_VERSION, 
                                           credentials=credentials)
```

Where am I missing the parameter? As far as I can see flow.run_console() doesn't take a parameter called scope. Is this the correct process to be using to accomplish this?

Comment: Did you solved it? Could you share your solution?